# Увеличение изображения после конца левого блока

Tags: html, css

Есть текстовый блок с левой стороны. По правой стороне идет блок с изображениями. Идея в том, что бы после окончания текста, правый блок с картинками становился шириной 100%, и изображения занимали всю ширину.
Игрался много, но желаемого результата не получил. По правой стороне будет столько картинок, сколько влезет. Нужна динамика.

Ну и собственно вопрос, как заставить изображения увеличится после окончания левого блока?

```css
.container{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}


.container .left_sidebar{
  width:745px;
  margin:0 0 0 55px;
}

.container .right_sidebar img{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.left{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <aside class="left_sidebar left">
  <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
  <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
  <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
  <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
 </aside>
 
 <aside class="right_sidebar">
  <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
  <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
  <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
  <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
 </aside>
</div>
```

[image: иллюстрация]

Comment: Увы, но нет....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так годится? Можно открыть сниппет на полном экране и менять ширину окна, чтобы текст прижимал вправо разное количество картинок.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/h3yy14gp/

```css
.for-text {
  float: left;
}
.for-image {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.for-image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="for-text">
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph Paragraph.</p>
  <p>Paragraph Paragraph Paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/" alt=""></div>
<div class="for-image"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .left_sidebar {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 0 0 55px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.container .right_sidebar {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 0 0 55px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container .right_sidebar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.container .full_sidebar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside class="left_sidebar">
    <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
    <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
    <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
    <p>тут какой-то текст</p>
  </aside>
   <aside class="right_sidebar">
    <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
  </aside>
  
  <aside class="full_sidebar">
  <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
  <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
  <img src="http://toursdekiev.com.ua/files/Building_Himeras.jpg">
</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: В данном случае картинки не увеличиваются, и не занимают всю ширину. Про увеличение мой косяк, не явно написал. Картинки которые ниже, должны увеличивать свой размер до 100%

Comment: Все равно не то. У меня может быть текста на 2 длинны картинки сбоку, и на 3 картинки.

Comment: FanG это уже дело js , на css такое (если не ошибаюсь) не делается , математические функции еле поддерживаются но не такие

Comment: Да если текст по высоте значительно больше то js нужно использовать.  Можешь посмотреть http://masonry.desandro.com/ может поможет.

Comment: Dmitriy Kondratiuk  масонри тут ни приделах , ему не кирпичики надо делать - у меня даже в голову не лезет - как реализовать

Comment: ну как вариант узнавать высоту блока с текстом с нее вычитать высоту первой картинки если значение больше некого порога то вставлять в правый блок вторую картинку и так далее, после того как правый блок будет больше порогового значения вставлять картинки в большой блок. Вот как реализовать это да сложный вопрос.

Comment: а оно стоит того ?